# Test if QQuickView (QWindow) is full-screen in Qt 5.0.x

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

For a `QWidget` we can test if it is displayed in full-screen with [`flags() & Qt::WindowFullScreen`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#WindowType-enum).
The same doesn't seem to work with [`QQuickView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qquickview.html) (which is a `QQuickWindow` which is a `QWindow`), as [`QWindow::flags()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qwindow.html#flags-prop) always returns [`Qt::WindowMinimized`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#WindowType-enum), whatever the reason might be. I display the window using this code:

```
QQuickView w;
w.setSource(...);
w.show(); /* or */ w.showFullScreen();
```

In Qt 5.1, [`QWindow::visibility()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qwindow.html#visibility-prop) was introduced. It returns a new enum type which contains [`QWindow::FullScreen`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qwindow.html#Visibility-enum) and behaves properly.

How can I test if a `QWindow` is shown in full-screen **in Qt 5.0.x**? I want to implement a "toggle full-screen" function. Keeping track of the current state seems to be the wrong way (yet it would be a possible work-around). I don't understand why [`QWindow::flags()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qwindow.html#flags-prop) returns `Qt::WindowMinimized`...

Code to reproduce issue (press <kbd>RETURN</kbd> to see the output of [`QWindow::flags()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qwindow.html#flags-prop)):

**test.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    signal test();
    width: 100; height: 100
    focus: true
    Keys.onReturnPressed: test()
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QDebug>

class Test : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void test() {
        QQuickItem *item = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(sender());
        QQuickWindow *window = item->window();
        qDebug() << window->flags(); // Will print 0x1 == Qt::WindowMinimized
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);

    QQuickView w;
    w.setSource(QUrl("...(relative path to the qml file from above)..."));
    w.show(); // Please also test w.showFullScreen();

    QObject::connect(w.rootObject(), SIGNAL(test()),
                     new Test, SLOT(test()));

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**test.pro**

```
QT += quick
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Comment: Did you try with this `bool isFullScreen() const`

Comment: @Samoth I can't find such a function. Did you?

Comment: You can look at actual Qt version and take code from it. Are there any real reasons to stay at 5.0?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Not anymore. I wanted to keep Qt 5.0 support for my application, but I dropped it, also for other reasons, and require >= 5.1 now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is deprecated and not relevant anymore as of today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use method [QWindow::windowState()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#windowState). It returns key [Qt::WindowFullScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowState-enum) that you seek.

```
bool isFullScreen = w.windowState().testFlag(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
```

Comment: Well, the question is more than deprecated now, as I asked for a solution specifically for Qt 5.0 (before 5.1, when `visibility()` was introduced, as noted in the other answer). Thank you for still answering it! :)

Comment: Actually for me it's still relevant because i support code that should work with Qt 5.0.